# The [math] tag is pointless

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

In my opinion, the tag [math] is pretty useless, as we already have the following tags:

- Geometry
- Arithmetic
- Combinatorics
- Probability
- Number-theory

Every math puzzle can be identified with one of those categories, except Algebra problems, but puzzling isn't meant for Algebra I guess.
What I'm trying to say is that [math] is a superset of the other tags, it's redundant, so I suggest to remove it.
What do you guys think about it?

Comment: There might be situations where the questioner wants to state that mathematical ability is needed to solve a puzzle, but without explicitly stating what branch of maths is involved.

Comment: That's a very very rare situation, which perhaps justifies just 2-3 out of the 350 problems where the tag [math] was used.

Comment: mathematic problems are fobidden on the whole seemingly http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2783/are-math-textbook-style-problems-on-topic

Comment: I meant math puzzles, I edited the first post.

Answer (score 9):

### I disagree.

Firstly, there are many branches of maths which don't currently have their own tags: **analysis**, **calculus**, **algebra**, **trigonometry**, **topology**, and so on. You could make a case for creating tags for all of these, but that would be a lot of tags to create that currently have no puzzles assigned to them. You also say "puzzling isn't meant for Algebra", but I bet you I could write an interesting puzzle on every one of the tagless topics I've mentioned!

Secondly, your argument could be extended to say that any tag for a topic whose subtopics have their own tags should be burninated. So [probability], say, should be abolished in favour of [random-walk], [gambling], [dice], [cards], [coin-tossing], [random-selection], and whatever other subcategories we can find? **It can be useful to have a more general tag even if its subtopics are covered by other tags.**

- To take an example from [Science Fiction and Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/), a more well-established Stack Exchange, there is a Harry Potter tag (the second most popular tag overall) which covers any question relevant to the Harry Potter universe, but there are also tags for Voldemort, Horcruxes, Severus Snape, Hogwarts, J K Rowling, and so on. The tags for Tolkien, Lord of the Rings, The Hobbit, The Silmarillion and Middle-Earth are all among the most popular tags there, but any question tagged Tolkien or Middle-Earth is also likely to be tagged with one of Lord of the Rings, The Hobbit, or The Silmarillion.
- To take an even more well-established example, look at the tags on Meta sites such as this very one we're on. Every question must be tagged [bug], [discussion], [support], or [feature-request]. Now let's say you want to report a bug related to one of the site's features. On a broad level, the site doesn't have many features: posting questions, posting answers, posting comments, voting, starting bounties, tagging, chat. Each of these has its own tag. Does that mean the [bug] tag should be abolished? No! General tags have their uses.

Thirdly, as squeamish ossifrage [mentioned](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2875/the-math-tag-is-pointless#comment5969_2875), there are some puzzles which are mathematical in nature but a) are related to **maths as a whole** (I couldn't find an example of this offhand) or b) are such that the OP **doesn't want to specify what kind of maths is involved** for fear of making the puzzle too easy (such as [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5019/brothers-cousins-and-foes-what-am-i) of mine).

Finally, let's recall what tags are for. As stated in the [help centre](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/tagging), tags are useful for helping people to identify the questions that are most interesting to them. There must be many people (such as myself) who are interested in a wide range of different mathematical puzzles. **It's much easier to search through all puzzles tagged [math]** than to have to search under many different tags for all the different parts of maths; and if people decide to focus on just one or two of their favourite areas so as not to have to search so many tags, we might lose a lot of high-quality contribution in the tags they're no longer following!