# Should we have a specific tag for "What is an XYZ Word/Phrase/Number etc." puzzles?

Tags: discussion, tags

There is a multitude of "What is an XYZ item™" questions on Puzzling.SE, and although there are some bad ones, most of them are interesting. However, they do not have a tag to be easily searched (despite some of them provide search link as [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463), but not all of them keep the original "canonical" form, so many questions are not shown in the search results).

They are usually tagged with [pattern](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pattern) and some "item-specific" tag (e.g. [word-property](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-property) for words, [number-sequence](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-sequence) for numbers etc.), but I believe it's too generic for them.

So, should we create a tag for these puzzles only, like [trademarked-items](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trademarked-items) or so? 
(Sorry, I cannot devise a better name for it, but the community definitely can do it.)

*Update:* There was a very similar [question](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5437/what-is-a-puzzle-tag) asked about 3,5 years ago, but it seems that it's not a duplicate because of the following reasons:

1) The [word-property](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-property) tag can be only applied to word-related question, but there are many questions in which the object of a property (the "item") is not a word (e.g. phrase, number - maybe some other types will come in the future), but the questions obviously share the same topic, so it's (in my opinion) natural to have a common tag for them. It's a bit strange to tag non-word quesions with [word-property](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-property).

2) On the other hand (like @GarethMcCaughan said), the [word-property](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-property) tag
was created not only for the puzzles of the very same type. I also believe that it's good, since [word-property](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-property) tag name implies that the puzzle tagged with it has to do something with the properties of certain words, so this puzzle absolutely *does not have* to be of that very form.

Comment: [tag:what-is-a-question], perhaps?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Unfortunately, it does not. Addind the reasoning for it.

Comment: Of course, I've meant "adding". Did not see the typo until the point that I cannot edit the comment anymore :(

Answer (score 5):

The [word-property](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-property) tag was created specifically for this sort of puzzle (though it might apply to some other puzzles); see the discussion in [an earlier Meta question](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5437/what-is-a-puzzle-tag) on exactly this topic.

The conclusion then was that we *should* create a tag, that [word-property](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-property) was a good name, and that its description should be sufficiently generic that it doesn't specifically require questions to have "What is an X Word (tm)?" titles. That still seems reasonable to me.

I guess the existence of a variant with numbers rather than words means that you can't use the tag system to find everything with a "What is an X?" title, but if you need *that* you can just search for "what is a" and "what is an", almost all the results for which are puzzles of this type.

Comment: However, there are now many questions which *do* have the [tag:word-property] tag but are completely unrelated to this.

Comment: A fairly small number. Probably some of them are mis-tagged, but it was a deliberate decision _not_ to define [word-property] in a way that _only_ applies to puzzles that are explicitly of this type.