# Should limerick be a separate tag from poetry?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I was looking through the different tags and noticed that although the old [haiku](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haiku) tag had been made a synonym of [poetry](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry), [limerick](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limerick) is still its own tag. I wanted to ask if there is a reason for this distinction in the first place, and if not should limerick questions be merged to poetry as well?

Comment: I don't think there's a specific reason as much as users didn't *realize* there was a limerick tag. I definitely think it should be merged

Comment: Hmm, interesting. There are rather a lot of things tagged "limerick". If you're looking for a puzzle and remember that it's in limerick form or features a limerick, that more specific knowledge might be useful, so I'm not sure it should be merged with "poetry".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Tags are allowed to have subtags.**

Just like [we're allowed to have](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2880/5373) both the general [mathematics](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics) tag and specific tags like [geometry](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry), [number-theory](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory), [combinatorics](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics), and so on, it's also fine to have both the general [poetry](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry) tag and specific tags like [limerick](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limerick), [haiku](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haiku), and so on. Is the [limerick](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limerick) subtag causing any trouble for the site? Being misused on questions, acting as a meta tag, anything like that?

I wouldn't especially miss it if it was gone - it seems unusually specific for a tag, and not really describing a type of *puzzle* so much as a type of presentation - but it's been used on 30+ questions so evidently some people like it and find it useful.